# How to identify hidden field using only class name using VBScript

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript, ui-automation

I am trying to automate a SharePoint form using VBScript as I don't have permission to install any software on the machine.

Currently there is one field, which is a textarea by default. It will not be visible and on clicking on it its classname changes :(, expect class there is no other field to identify it.

I tried accessing it using the classname, but VBScript could not find it, 
classname has some whitespace so I am elemenating it. Below is the code.

```
For Each elem In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    Dim r, s
    Set r = New RegExp
    r.Global  = True
    r.Pattern = "^\s+|\s+$"
    id = r.Replace(id, "")
    s  = r.Replace(elem.getAttribute("class"), "")

    If s = id Then
        WScript.Echo "found class"
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        WshShell.SendKeys "found"
        s.value = "found"
        elem.value = "found"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I even tried the below code but actions can not be performed, Echo message is shown but click or data enter actions are not performed.

```
AllObjects = IE.Document.all.length
 for i=0 to AllObjects
    If  Trim(IE.Document.all(i).getAttribute("class")) = "nicEdit-main" Then
        IE.Document.all(i).Click
        IE.Document.all(i) = "found"
        WScript.Echo i, IE.Document.all(i).getAttribute("class")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: some one gave this question negative point, why ? This question is asked by many people and i found the answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is confusing, i have tried this before it did not work but now it is working, just use `focus` method and it works

```
IE.Document.all(i).focus
```

and

```
WsShell.SendKeys "text"
```

enjoy :D